# How to prevent ClickEvent propagation if fields have validation errors?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a basic `BeanFieldGroup` editor with some textfields. I expose the save-`Button` so that `Presenter` classes can register to it.

Problem: when the `TextField` elements in view have validation errors, I would like to prevent the propagation of the clickevent (as invalid input values requires further user input and should not trigger any other actions).

But how can I prevent them?

```
class UserView {
    private TextField username = new TextField("username");
    private Button save;
    private BeanFieldGroup<User> editor;

    public UserView() {
        editor = new BeanFieldGroup<User>(User.class);

        save = new Button("Save", new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                try {
                    editor.commit();
                } catch (CommitException e) {
                    //how can I prevent the click event to be routed to the presenter?
                    Notification.show("Form invalid");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public getSaveBtn() {
        return save;
    }

}


class UserPresenter implements Button.ClickListener {
    void bind() {
        view.getSaveBtn().addClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //this should be prevented if username field has validation errors in view
        doa.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that you register two `ClickListeners` for your save button. The listener in your presenter effectively circumvents the validation logic of your `editor` FieldGroup since it is invoked regardless of the outcome of the FieldGroup's validation. What you need is a method on your presenter that will exclusively be called when the input has been successfully validated.

So, the code of your ClickListener in `UserView` should look something like this:

```
save = new Button("Save", new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        try {
            editor.commit();

            // no CommitException thrown until now, so go ahead and tell the presenter:
            presenter.doSave(entity);
        } catch (CommitException e) {
            // validation failed -> don't tell the presenter
            Notification.show("Form invalid");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: OK this works, though I feel that from design perspective it is not right to have the presenter instance inside the view.

Comment: Yes, that's how MVP works :) The View must have access to the Presenter, otherwise it can't communicate with the rest of the application. The Presenter is the link between the View and the Model.

Comment: As far as https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin reads, in fact MVP means the view has no knowledge about the presenter, only the presenter about the view.

Comment: Quoting from the blog: "The are design alternatives for the view. It could receive the listener in its constructor, or it could just know the presenter." Of course, you could do without a reference from the View to the Presenter. But your code would become unwieldy, since you would need to introduce your own events/listeners (such as a ValidationSucceededEvent for instance). I think this would be overkill in your case.